# What is percentage of "redness" in a set of bags of white balls?

Tags: probability

A standard bag has 100 balls in total, in which balls are either white of red.

We need to find average redness of one bag, if we mix all bags of the following distribution:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate total number of red balls and divide it by total number of bags. You will find average number of red balls in one randomly chosen bag.